# SecKeyGeneratePair returns errSecUnimplemented

Tags: ios, security-framework

Im attempting to implement an RSA encryption algorithm into my iOS app, but when I attempt to generate a public and private key pair, the function returns me the errSecUnimplemented error.  I am using the 5.1 SDK and targeting 5.1 at the moment.

Can I not use this function, or did I set up something wrong in attempting to generate the pair?

Here is my code for the key generation:

```
SecKeyRef publicKey, privateKey;
CFDictionaryRef parameters;
const void* keys[] = {kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA};
int keySize = 1024;
const void *values[] = {kSecAttrKeySizeInBits, &keySize};

parameters = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 2, NULL, NULL);
OSStatus ret = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey);
if ( ret == errSecSuccess )
{
    NSLog(@"Key success!");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Key Failure! %li", ret);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've revised it to just complete the solution for you.  1) You need to use a CFNumberRef and not a pointer to an int for the numerical value.  2) The values need to be the values, the keys need to be the keys - you were mixing a key and value in each of "keys" and "values".

```
SInt32 iKeySize = 1024;
CFNumberRef keySize = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &iKeySize);
const void* values[] = { kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, keySize };
const void* keys[] = { kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits };
CFDictionaryRef parameters = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 2, NULL, NULL);

SecKeyRef publicKey, privateKey;
OSStatus ret = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey);
if ( ret == errSecSuccess )
    NSLog(@"Key success!");
else 
    NSLog(@"Key Failure! %li", ret);
```

Comment: I get the following error with ARC enabled: `Use __bridge_retained to make an ARC object available as a +1 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *')`  Last time I tried to use a `__bridge` cast everything went haywire, is this a simpler, but safe case to do so?

Comment: And even if I do a `__bridge_retained` cast, I still get the -4 error

Comment: Edited to be complete.  You should be good to go (so long as I didn't leave any typos).

Comment: I get a warning with your code because `values` is of type `void*` not `void**`, and if I make it into `const void* values[]` i get a bad access exception, and still the -4 error if I leave it as just a `const void *`

Comment: Apologies, you should pass the ref to your keys and values, edited

Comment: Those still aren't the right types.  `CFDictionaryCreate` is looking for two `const void **`, and `keys` by itself is a `const void **` adding the reference to it, you're making it a `const void ***`, and in your latest edit, `values` is still written as just a `const void *`, not a `const void *[]`

Comment: Oh man... I see it now.  I didn't put the array parens for one of the declarations.  I should mention I'm doing this all on my iPhone.

Comment: I tried that combination, and that is how I end up with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception being thrown on `SecKeyGeneratePair`

Comment: That's what I get for not checking my work with a compiler.  values needed the CFNumberRef itself, not a reference to it. Code updated...

Comment: Ah HA! Finally success!  Thank you for all your help, I searched for quite a while to find sample code for this method, but just nothing existed anywhere...

Comment: Yay!  The power of crowd sourcing and persistence! :)

Comment: For those using the example code here, 1024 bit RSA keys aren't considered secure anymore, you should use 2048 or 4096 bit keys instead.

Comment: Do we have this in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be:

```
const void* keys[] = {kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits};
int keySize = 1024;
const void *values[] = {kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, &keySize};
```

i.e., the keys should be the keys of the dict and the values the values, currently you have one (key,value) pair in keys and one in values.

Comment: I get a bad access exception when I do it this way, even with setting the key size as nob outlined above

Comment: Perhaps http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7339-rsa-encryption.html helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `kCFAllocatorSystemDefault` instead of `kCFAllocatorDefault` return `errSecSuccess`.